# Django + svelte + ngrok: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote

Tags: django, cors, svelte, ngrok

I am working on Django + Svelte platform and each one of them is hosted on the local server the local hosts work fine with no errors
when I tried to use ngrok tunnels to be able to allow my friends to test the platform I got this error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://452c-102-159-49-36.ngrok-free.app/api/courses/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200`

this is the API call from the svelte component:

```
  async function fetchCourseOptions() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://452c-102-159-49-36.ngrok-free.app/api/courses/"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      courseSelected = true;
      return data.courses;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error while fetching course options:", error);
      return [];
    }
  }
```

this is the tunnels config in ngrok

```
tunnels:
  django:
    proto: http
    addr: 127.0.0.1:8000
  svelte:
    proto: http
    addr: 5173
```

and these are the domains:

```
Forwarding                    https://25fc-102-159-49-36.ngrok-free.app -> http://localhost:5173                                                       Forwarding                    https://452c-102-159-49-36.ngrok-free.app -> http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

I tried adding the addresses to the cors allowed origins and allowed hosts in Django settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["452c-102-159-49-36.ngrok-free.app", "localhost"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "profikapp.apps.ProfikappConfig",
    "smart_selects",
    "api.apps.ApiConfig",
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "profik.urls"

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:5173",
    "https://25fc-102-159-49-36.ngrok-free.app",
    "https://452c-102-159-49-36.ngrok-free.app",
    "https://5ab8-102-159-49-36.ngrok-free.app",
]
```

but it didn't work it's still giving me errors and I don't understand why. I need help at least to figure the cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

You can try to allow all, then see the source of the request:

To do so:

```
#settings.py

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

#add this to your function, it'll print the source of the request
print(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

DO NOT USE IT IN PROD

Comment: this didn't work. and the thing is I am not getting anything in the Python server no logs no requests the data doesn't load and the error shows in the console in the browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).